# Collision not being detected

Tags: xcode5, sprite-kit

I have two sprites, my player and a wall ( from a tilemap) that collides. Below i have pasted the code for the player and wall

```
Player.m
    - (instancetype)init {
        SKTextureAtlas *atlas =
        [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed: @"char"];
        SKTexture *texture = [atlas textureNamed:@"player"]; texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
        if (self = [super initWithTexture:texture])
        { self.name = @"player";
            CGFloat minDiam = MIN(self.size.width, self.size.height);
            minDiam = MAX(minDiam-16, 4);
            self.physicsBody =
            [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:minDiam/2.0];
            self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=PCPlayerCategory;    
            self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =
            PCWallCategory;
            self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
            self.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
            self.physicsBody.friction = 0;
            self.physicsBody.linearDamping = 0;
        }
        return self;
    }
```

tilemap.m

```
        SKSpriteNode *tile = [layer tileAtCoord:coord];
        tile.name=@"wall";
        tile.physicsBody =
        [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:tile.size];
        tile.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = PCWallCategory;
          tile.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =
          PCPlayerCategory;
        tile.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        tile.physicsBody.friction = 0;
          tile.physicsBody.restitution=0;
```

In my mainscene.m

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (PCWallCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {
    NSLog(@"SUCCESS"); }
```

However, even if my player is sitting on my wall I dont see that NSLog showing up, would like to get some help and insight into this please.
Thank you

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
  uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
  if (collision == (PCWallCategory|PCPlayerCategory)) {

    NSLog(@"SUCCESS");
    onGround=YES;
  }else
  {
    onGround=NO;
  }

}
```

Comment: incorrect use of categoryBitMask ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/22804376/201863

Comment: Instead of the collisionBitMask, you need to set the contactTestBitMask with the same values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `collisionTestBitMask` only defines which types of bodies can collide with the physicsBody. In order to trigger the contact delegate when two bodies collide, you need to set the `contactTestBitMask`.

So, the physicsBody should be defined in this way:

```
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask=PCPlayerCategory;    
self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = PCWallCategory;
```