# ambient light excludes 1 object from getting affected

Tags: ios, scenekit

Is it possible to specify which nodes the light source affects? I would like to use ambient light but exclude 1 object from getting affected. I did the the homework and the appropriate property looks like **categoryBitMask**.

I followed this answer at [Physics bodies other than my player won't call didBeginContact when colliding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799213/physics-bodies-other-than-my-player-wont-call-didbegincontact-when-colliding/22804376#22804376) and set categoryBitMask of ambientLight to 1 and objects to 4 (in bits that is 1 and 100). I also tried setting it to 100 and 1 but it didn't work too. What am I missing? I set all categoryBitMasks in Scene Editor.